# Disable automatic mounting of partitions in Windows 10 on startup

Tags: windows-10

I have two hard drives, one having OS (linux and windows) and the other formatted to ntfs for storage purposes, I want to have it mounted only when I need it. Problem is Windows automatically mount the second drive on startup, I want to disable this behavior only for that drive, just like removing it from `/etc/fstab` on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: remove the drive letter in [Windows disk management GUI](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-assign-permanent-drive-letter-windows-10)

Method 2: fsutil volume dismount D: